# Remove All (Multiple) Grub Loaders

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

So i dual-booted Ubuntu, then Parrot Security OS. Their Loaders wont go away even after i format the partition the OS were installed. Ive tried boot-repair but it didnt help. I have the paste2.org link. When i boot, the ubuntu just shows a black screen with the grub loader and you can type in it. Parrot os grub loader shows grub rescue mode. I want to get rid of all Grub bootloaders and try dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu again.

Answer (score 1):

On an EFI-based system, boot loaders reside on the [EFI System Partition (ESP),](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) but many distributions (including Ubuntu) configure GRUB to rely on configuration and support files elsewhere -- in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` in the case of Ubuntu. Thus, if you delete the Ubuntu root (`/`) partition (or, if you use one, a separate `/boot` partition), GRUB will remain behind, but won't be able to load a boot menu because its configuration file will be gone.

Since you say you want to re-install Ubuntu, there are a number of ways you can work around this issue:

- **Delete the GRUB files now, then re-install** -- You can use an emergency disk or EFI shell (if your computer provides one built in) to delete the Ubuntu and Parrot OS boot loaders from the ESP. The Ubuntu boot loader would be in `EFI/ubuntu` on the ESP; you can delete that entire directory. I don't know offhand where the Parrot OS boot loader would be, but it would normally be a subdirectory of `EFI` on the ESP. Once these files are gone, you can re-install Ubuntu.
- **Skip deleting GRUB; just re-install** -- When you re-install Ubuntu, it will write a fresh copy of GRUB to the ESP, overwriting its old copy. This is likely to be simpler and easier than trying to muck with the existing files. The main drawback is that it won't delete the Parrot OS boot loader (unless that's an Ubuntu derivative, in which case it might have put GRUB where Ubuntu does).
- **Adjust the boot order** -- Many EFIs let you adjust the boot order via a menu in their firmware setup utilities. You can use this feature to raise Windows above the `ubuntu` entry and whatever Parrot OS created. You can do the same thing with `efibootmgr` in Linux or [EasyUEFI](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) in Windows -- but of course you'd need an emergency disk to boot into Ubuntu to use `efibootmgr`. (There's an easier way to get into Windows temporarily; see the next bullet point.) The main point of doing this rather than just re-installing is that you could then use Windows for a while before you attempt to re-install Ubuntu.
- **Boot Windows temporarily** -- Chances are you can boot to Windows temporarily by using your firmware's built-in boot manager. You probably used this tool to boot your Ubuntu installation medium, and you'd access it in the same way. (Unfortunately, details of how to do this vary greatly from one computer to another. It's usually done by pressing Esc, Enter, or a function key shortly after you turn on the computer.)

Whatever you do, you should ***NOT*** delete the ESP entirely. The Windows boot loader resides there, in `EFI/Microsoft/Boot`, so deleting the ESP, or even just deleting that directory, will render Windows unbootable until you restore the Windows boot loader using Windows recovery tools.